# Use timers to handle async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

The following code might not be the best approach to handle asynchronous. I know that using callback functions, promises, rxjs is a cleaner take. However, I would like to know if there is a very big problem when using it.

```
   var response = null;

   var int = setInterval(()=> {
                                if(window.response != null){ 
                                    console.log('arrived in interval'); 
                                    clearInterval(int);
                                } else { 
                                    console.log('waiting');
                                }
                             }, 500);

    $.get('url', (response)=>{
                             console.log('async arrived'); 
                             window.response = response;
    });
```

Thanks,

Comment: The setInterval function takes a callback... you’re already using callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

- It's inefficient.
- You can only do one asynchronous request at a time, since they all share the same `window.response` variable. Or you need to keep track of several different variables for individual requests.
- Global `window.`?! Yuck. You're just asking for problems down the line.
- You're using a callback anyway, two in fact. One to set `window.response = response`, and another one for `setInterval`.
- It's hard to track, debug and read.
- It's more code than the straight callback alternative.